# detect body using OpenCV detectMultiScale

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier

I need to detect the people in the picture. Here, I use haar cascade to detect the body. However, the result shows no changes. There is no rectangular on the image so I want to know what happened.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

    argv[1] = "C:/people.jpg";//test image
    Mat image;
    Mat img;
    Mat gray;
    vector<Rect>human;
    CascadeClassifier detectorBody;
    string cascadeBody = "C:/opencv/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades_cuda/haarcascade_fullbody.xml";
    bool loaded = detectorBody.load(cascadeBody);

    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);//turn to gray
    detectorBody.detectMultiScale(gray, human, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(12, 28));

    for (int i = 0; i < human.size(); i++) {

        rectangle(gray, human[i].tl(), human[i].br(), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);

    }
    namedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    imshow("Display", image);
    namedWindow("gray", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("gray", gray);


    waitKey(0);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't think that the lena image will work with body detection. There is no body in the image. Body detector essentially detects the torso region from knees to neck.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad example. Actually, the image I used is the image from INRIA's dataset, which contains a full body. I will go to correct it.Thx!

Comment: I ran your code on my end using a few generic images with people in them. It draws the rectangles around some of the people properly. It doesn't do a very good job at the actual detection (lots of misses or false positives) but I think that is the nature of the haar cascade method. I think the quality of detection comes down to the parameters fed to the detectMultiScale method. Without seeing your image, I'd recommend tweaking those.

Comment: I don't know why I can't see any draw on my figure. So you can detect without changing any code?I know this will be a lot of false positives because my next homework is to correct those using adaboost. Anyway, thank for your reply.

Comment: Yes, your code works without modification on the images that I tested. Here are the links to the images I used: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/5b/ed/4a/5bed4a512eb9e1b380c5a195711365fd.jpg and https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-collection-back-view-of-walking-people-going-people-in-motion-set-backside-view-of-person-104447549.jpg